# Diagonalization of a Hamiltonian quadratic in position and momentum

Tags: operators, hamiltonian

Consider the Hamiltonian
$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}T_{i,j}p_ip_j+V_{i,j}x_ix_j
$$
with momentum operators $p_i$ and position operators $x_i$. If $V_{i,j}=V_{i,i}$ for all $j$ and $T_{i,j}=T_{i,i}$ for all $j$, it would be clear how to diagonalize the Hamiltonian. This question is motivated by the computation subsequent to equation (20) in the paper of [Elgart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0212631.pdf).

Comment: why not find the (classical) normal modes and start with these?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0212631

Comment: I am sorry, but what is actually the question?

Comment: I want to diagonalize $H$.

Comment: how would you find these normal modes @ZeroTheHero?

Comment: That would be covered in any class.mech textbook.

Comment: How to find normal modes: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96184/23785

Comment: Is it 1D problem? try using transfer matrix method.